# output.get breaking IDE

Tags: arrays, error-handling, dice

[image: full code + errors]

So I was making a dice roller by myself, and the IDE doesn't seem to detect a problem with my code. But when I run it, the code seems to fall apart at the very last line. I'm assuming there's something wrong with "output.get(numOfDice)" but I'm not sure. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It should be `numOfDice - 1` if you want the last index

Comment: Oh, I already fixed it, but thanks!